# How to test the if condition in JSP?

Tags: html, jsp

I want to only display the error message in JSP. This means if the error variable is present then its message will be displayed and the form will be hidden.

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${errorMessage ne null}">
           error; ${errorMessage}  //I have the error
         </c:when>

         <c:otherwise>
<form action="send-mail" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>

                <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="email"> </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="Submit" value="Reset Password">  </td>
                <td><input type="reset" value="Cancel">  </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </form>
         </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

thank you for helping me;

Comment: And what is your problem? What is not working / working different than you expect?

Comment: If the `errorMessage ! = Null`, I want to have on my html page only the error message. Therefore,**the form no longer appears on the page**

Comment: please try like this , <c:when test="${not empty errorMessage}">

Comment: Thank you @GurkanYesilyurt , it works

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, it is necessary to replace:

```
<c:when test="${errorMessage ne null}">
```

by

```
<c:when test="${not empty errorMessage}">
```